# Vue v-model bind issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

Hi I have been on this issue for several days now. I am trying to bind data to input text using v-model of Vue. My Vue is installed in my project, and the `cdn` link added in header. The textbox simply shows the data for a split second on reload and then disappears. Is it maybe an installation problem? I installed npm vue directly in my Laravel project on my console.

My HTML:

```
<div id='postEdit'>

  <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" v-model="post.body">

</div>
```

My Vue:

```
var edit = new Vue({
  el: '#postEdit',
  data: {
    post: {
      body: 'this is body'
    }
  },

});
```

My output when I run edit.post in console:

```
Object { body: Getter & Setter, … }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data property is wrong, it needs to be a function returning an object. Change like this:

```
data () {
  return {
    post: {
      body: 'this is body'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That did not solve the problem, tried it before and tried again and the result stays exactly the same.

Comment: Regardless, data must be declared this way. Did you clear your browser cache just to be sure the changes were in effect?

Comment: Just cleared my entire history and cache - still the same.

Answer (score 0):

[Vue.js documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data) says that in `data` option you MUST use **Plain objects**:

> Vue will recursively convert its properties into getter/setters to make it “reactive”. **The object must be plain**: native objects such as browser API objects and prototype properties are ignored. A rule of thumb is that data should just be data - it is not recommended to observe objects with their own stateful behavior.

For your example I'd go with a computed property returning the `body` property of your `post`.

I mean something like [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sd81mbL9/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I was so sure it would work! But it didn't so now I'm starting to think there is something wrong with my Vue or Node installation perhaps?

Comment: I am not familiar with Laravel, so I don't know how Vue setup fits in it, sorry! However could please provide a complete example of your sourcecode to see what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Just make your data a function and check again. [proof](https://jsfiddle.net/juervvy6/)

```
<div id='postEdit'>
  <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="form-control" v-model="post.body">
</div>

var edit = new Vue({
el: '#postEdit',
data: function() { 
  return {
      post: {
      body: 'this is bodygfdgfd'
      }
   }
 }
});
```

oh, and this console thing... try edit.post.body

You see {getter, setter} because Vue "compiles" data object using Object.defineProperty method to observe changes in data. Under the hood getters works just fine, trust me ;)

Comment: My v-model still won't bind the 'post.body' in the textbox

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/horcrux88/sd81mbL9/1/
The fiddle works... But in my Laravel application it won't work...